# Blurry Images Wordpress 5.8.1

Tags: images, uploads, media, media-library

I've tried to

1. Use .png instead of .jpg
2. Disable wordpress default compression `add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});`
3. Switch themes to test
4. Disable plugins
5. Regenerate thumbnails multiple times
6. Re-upload media many times
7. Define exact width and height for each image
8. Disable lazy loading

The images still look blurry once they are uploaded. My images are all optimised and in the exact width and height. I didn't have these issues with previous versions of wordpress. What else should I do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Blurry how? Where? Are the images being resized?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The images are not resized. All images uploaded to wordpress are blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why @fuxia deleted my first answer, but I may be able to help. My original answer was to say that I was experiencing the same issue. I have discovered the issue and perhaps it will help you.

In the Jetpack plugin there are a series of settings under the Performance tab: Enable site accelerator and Enable lazy loading for images. I turned both of those off in their entirety and my images are now crystal clear as before.

So in my problem, WordPress 5.8.1 had nothing to do with the issue.